# how to store string and float from a file to a struct?

Tags: c, cs50, strtok

Im trying to store string and floats from a file to a struct. I have managed to store floats to the struct, but the strings won't work the same.

my file looks like this

```
Names                 weight(kg)
John Smith            56.5
Joe                   59.75
Jose                  60.0
```

output:

```
Jose                  56.5
Jose                  59.75
Jose                  60.0
```

and here is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<cs50.h>
#include<string.h>

typedef struct
{
    string name;
    float weight;

}People;

int main(void)
{
    FILE *fp1;
    fp1 = fopen("file.txt","r");

    people person[255];

    if(!fp1)
    {
        printf("ERROR OPENING FILE");
        exit(1);
    }
    else
    {
        // store names and weights in person.name and person.weight from file 1
        get_nameAndWeight(fp1 ,person);
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        {
            printf("%s\t%.2f\n",person[i].name, person[i].weight);
        }
    }

}

void get_nameAndWeight(FILE *fp, people array[])
{
    char cur_line[255], *token;
    float weight;
    int i = 0;

    while(!feof(fp))
    {
        fgets(cur_line, sizeof(cur_line), fp);
        if(i == 0)
        {
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            token = strtok(cur_line, "\t\n ");
            while (token != NULL)
            {
                if(atof(token) != 0)
                {
                    array[i-1].weight = atof(token);
                }

                else
                {
                    array[i].name = token;
                }
                token = strtok(NULL, "\t\n ");
            }
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

What is wrong with my code? Is there another way to do this?

Comment: What is defining the typedef for `string name;`? I don't see that defined anywhere.

Comment: it's defined in cs50.h

Comment: `while(!feof(fp))` --> see [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5431941/2410359).

Comment: Mark,  Curious, who or what text suggested `while(!feof(fp))`?

Answer (score 3):

Note that strtok does not allocate any new memory, it modifies the array you passed in. So all of your objects are pointing to the same array `cur_line`.

You should allocate new memory for the names with [`strdup()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strdup) or some similar function. Something like:

```
array[i].name = strdup(token);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use strcpy for example !

You cannot just assign a string to a variable in c. You need to copy each char of the source to your destination string.

I guess strtok return a char*, so this char* is your source and name is your destination. Check strcpy manual.

I guess your following cs50 classes, so you don't have to deal with allocation if i remember well.
Still, it would relevant to check malloc and strdup function for you next exercices ;)